# incomplete type in nested name specifier in list, namespace

Tags: c++, list, struct

I have timers.h file like this:

```
namespace timers {
  struct timer {
    std::string next;
};

struct timers {
    std::list<timers::timer> timers_list;

    timers();
};
```

When I try compile my program whit it it shows:

```
modules/timers.h:23:13: error: incomplete type 'timers::timers' used  in nested name specifier
```

Why I can not use my struct in next struct as list?

Comment: You are using same name for namespace and struct, try changing one, does it make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`namespace` and `struct` have same name. When you type `timers::`, the compiler supposes this refers to the `struct`, not to the `namespace` (it is a kind of name shadowing).

So, because the class `timers` is not yet fully written, the compiler complains about an “incomplete” type.

It is a bad idea to have a `class` and `namespace` with same name, but your code can compile if you just type:

```
std::list<timer> timers_list;
```

Because you do not need to explicit the namespace, when you refer to something into the same one.